# find single MAX value per day

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have tired using parts of my previous question which was similar , but I as the table I am querying has multiple rows I can't seem to get one single max value for the day. I will then need to merge this with the previous question, but that's another thing I need to play with...

The table is simple, 2 columns

```
Date       |        Peak Power

1/1/2012 10:00:00 | 150.00

1/1/2012 10:12:00 | 120.00

1/1/2012 05:01:00 | 190.00

1/1/2012 01:35:00 | 500.00

1/1/2012 04:54:00 | 250.00
```

Result

```
Date | Peak Power each day

1/1/2012 10:00:00 | 500.00

2/1/2012 04:00:00 | 150.00
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont tell us what SQL product your using, so here is Sql Server 2008R2:

```
SELECT
CAST(t.DateColumn as DATE), MAX(t.PowerUsage) as 'Peak Power Each Day'
FROM [MyTable] t
GROUP BY CAST(t.DateColumn AS DATE)
```

here is MySql

```
SELECT
DATE(t.DateColumn), MAX(t.PowerUsage) as 'Peak Power Each Day'
FROM [MyTable] t
GROUP BY DATE(t.DateColumn)
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, no I will see if i get the 2 queries for different tables to work in 1 query.

Comment: Even though it's almost 8 years later, this answer returns only the date and the `MAX(t.PowerUsage)`. It doesn't return `datetime` (ie. _1/1/2012 10:00:00_)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to consolidate date-time records in dates?  There are a number of ways to do so, but I'd use this:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date, 120) AS "Date", MAX("Peak Power")
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date, 120)
```

You didn't specify your RDMS, but this will work in MS SQL.

Comment: There are almost certainly better alternatives to casting to `CHAR` (as @Kyro's answer shows).  In fact, the formatting value you've used is still a timestamp, so it's possibly still going to have to do the complete formatting (all ~26 characters), _then_ chop it down.  This is unlikely to allow use of any index on the date column .  It's possible (but I don't know SQL Server well enough) that using `CAST(... as DATE)` will have certain shortcuts built in, allowing it to use relevant indices.